# NSPredicate custom object pointer

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have interfaces like:

```
@interface Isle
@property (nonatomic, strong) id index_one; //has to be an id ={
@property (nonatomic, strong) id index_two;
@end


@interface Item
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name; //has to be an NSString
@end
```

Then I instantiate a search view controller:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Isle.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface TableViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* isles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* filter;
@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Isle* isle_one = [[Isle alloc] init];
    Isle* isle_two = [[Isle alloc] init];
    Isle* isle_three = [[Isle alloc] init];

    isle_one.index_one = [[Item alloc] init];
    isle_one.index_two = [[Item alloc] init];

    isle_two.index_one = [[Item alloc] init];
    isle_two.index_two = [[Item alloc] init];

    isle_three.index_one = [[Item alloc] init];
    isle_three.index_two = [[Item alloc] init];

    ((Item*)isle_one.index_one).name = @"ketchup";
    ((Item*)isle_one.index_two).name = @"hot sauce";
    ((Item*)isle_two.index_one).name = @"butter";
    ((Item*)isle_two.index_two).name = @"cheese";
    ((Item*)isle_three.index_one).name = @"cereal";
    ((Item*)isle_three.index_two).name = @"rice";

    _isles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: isle_one, isle_two, isle_three, nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate* res = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(index_one.name contains[cd] %@) OR (index_two.name contains[cd] %@)", @"ketchup", @"hot sauce"];

    _filter = [self.isles filteredArrayUsingPredicate: res];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [[self filter] count];
    }
    return [[self isles] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        Isle* isle = (Isle*)[self.filter objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t\t%@", ((Item*)isle.index_one).name, ((Item*)isle.index_two).name];
        cell.textLabel.text = str;
        return cell;
    }

    Isle* isle = (Isle*)[self.isles objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", ((Item*)isle.index_one).name, ((Item*)isle.index_two).name];
    cell.textLabel.text = str;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

But it says that it is not key-value compliant. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

My exact error is:

```
Project1[1688:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSSymbolicExpression 0x10e60a650> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

For filtering I did:

```
[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate: res];
```

Comment: Can you post the full exact error message? - Also your predicate has *two* `%@` placeholders, but only *one* argument (with a missing quotation mark). Please post the real code.

Comment: And `((Item*)isle_one).index_one.name = @"ketchup";` should be `((Item*)isle_one.index_one).name = @"ketchup";` ...

Comment: Ok. I edited the post with the error message and changes. I still get the same error though. It doesn't recognize `name` as a key.

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: It occurs on the predicate with format. I just did a clean and rebuilt it. It now recognizes `index_one` and `index_two` but not the name property. Same line. Same error.

Comment: When you *create* the predicate or when the predicate is *used* for filtering?

Comment: It only throws when it is used for filtering. It doesn't throw when I create it.

Comment: So it might help if you *show the code* where the predicate is used for filtering ???

Comment: I added that to the OP just now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with an array consisting only of `isle_one`. - Are you sure that the other array elements are of the same kind, i.e. their `index_one` and `index_two` properties are `Item` objects (so that they have a `name`) ? - It would be helpful if you could provide a self-contained example that compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added ALL the code I have to the OP. Only thing missing is the story board which is just a table view controller with a searchdisplaycontroller in it.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the problem. Can you set an Exception Breakpoint and post the stack back trace when the exception occurs? - (Btw: Are Isle and Item subclasses of NSObject? Your @interface definitions do you show the superclass.)

Comment: Hmm this is weird. Yes they are `NSObject`. I'll try debugging it more and see. I can't figure out why it does that. If I use a for-loop equivalent and populate the array manually instead of predicate filter, it works :l

Comment: I solved it.. I did: `NSPredicate* resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.%K.name contains[cd] %@) OR (SELF.%K.name contains[cd] %@)", @"index_one", searchText, @"index_two", searchText];`

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. I just wonder because your original predicate worked fine in my test code. Are "index_one", "index_two", "name" the real property names in your code, or did you change them for this question?

Comment: They are the real names. The code in the OP is the code I'm actually using. I was following a tutorial on learning search bars.